# IPhone4S is not allowing to text; use email nor certain apps

Tags: email, iphone, sms

*l accidentally did the reset statistics button on my phone and now my phone is all out of whack. What can I do to restore it back to its normal function?*

Answer (score 1):

I would do a restore back to factory settings, and then back up from an icloud or itunes backup. You do have a back up right?